# How do you create a dynamic select list from comma separated string?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am taking information from my database and trying to figure the best way to display it within the app.

This is my database info

> [{"form_input_id":"1","form_id":"6","title":"Please enter your room number?","input_type":"text","identifer":"room","choices":"s:0:\"\";","heading":"Valet Request"},{"form_input_id":"2","form_id":"6","title":"Please enter any comments or feedback.","input_type":"textarea","identifer":"feedback","choices":"s:0:\"\";","heading":"Valet Request"},{"form_input_id":"3","form_id":"6","title":"Please choose office","input_type":"select","identifer":"office","choices":"s:19:\"Sales, Reservations\";","heading":"Valet Request"},{"form_input_id":"18","form_id":"6","title":"Last Name","input_type":"text","identifer":"Last_Name","choices":"s:0:\"\";","heading":"Valet Request"},{"form_input_id":"19","form_id":"6","title":"Type of Car","input_type":"select","identifer":"Car_type","choices":"s:20:\"Buick, Olds, Ferrari\";","heading":"Valet Request"}]

I am able to pull everything the way I want to except choices. I am trying to create dynamic forms and need to create a select showing the choices.

My current controller:

```
    controller('FormCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading){

// Grab Form
var form = angular.fromJson(window.localStorage.getItem('form'));

// Set Title
$scope.title    = form[0].heading;

// Send Form Data
$scope.forms    = form;

})
```

And my view:

```
<ion-view title="Form" hide-nav-bar="true">
<ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-dark">
    <div class="buttons">
        <a href="#/lobby" class="button button-dark">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content id="dynamic" scroll="true" padding="true">
        <h2 class="text-center">{{title}}</h2>
        <form>
            <div ng-repeat="form in forms">
                <label>{{form.title}}</label>
                <div ng-if="form.input_type == 'text'">
                    <input type="text" name="{{form.identifier}}" />
                </div>
                <div ng-if="form.input_type == 'time'">
                    <input type="time" name="{{form.identifier}}" />
                </div>
                <div ng-if="form.input_type == 'textarea'">
                    <textarea name="{{form.identifier}}"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="form.input_type == 'select'">
                    <select name="{{form.identifier}}">
                              NEED TO FIGURE HOW TO DISPLAY CHOICES AS OPTIONS
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: where is ng-model for form inputs ?

Comment: The title here is misleading;  this has nothing to do with ng-repeat.  I updated this with a more appropriate title.  Also, this logic probably mostly works, but this heavy use of `ng-if` will slow down your page quite a bit, and not using `ng-model` could cause issues as well.  This is definitely not the most effective way to accomplish your task using angular.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your options from string. Something like that:

```
angular.forEach($scope.forms, function(item){
    item.options=item.choices.split('"')[1].split(',');
});
```

And tnen use ng-options in select:

```
<select name="{{form.identifier}}" ng-options="choice for choice in form.options" ng-model="Your model here"></select>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Thanks for the help I utilized angular-dynforms for the project.